# beautifulsoup can't find any tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a script that I've used for several years. One particular page on the site loads and returns soup, but all my finds return no result. This is old code that has worked on this site in the past. Instead of searching for a specific `<div>` I simplified it to look for any table, tr or td, with find or findAll. I've tried various methods of opening the page, including lxml - all with no results.

My interests are in the player_basic and player_records div's

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
import urllib2

url = "http://www.koreabaseball.com/Record/Player/HitterDetail/Basic.aspx?playerId=60456"

#html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
html = urllib2.urlopen(url,"lxml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

#div = soup.find('div', {"class":"player_basic"})  
#div = soup.find('div', {"class":"player_records"})  
item = soup.findAll('td')  
print item
```

Comment: Test the urllib2 part first, then proceed to the beautiful soup.

Comment: I printed the soup into a text file and everything is there.

Comment: Please add your expected output. I tried several thing an all of them work but I don't really know what you are looking for.

Comment: In this snippet of code, any non-null 'item.' The ultimate goal is to get the li's from "player_basic" and td's from "player_records"

Answer (score 0):

you're not reading the response. [try this:](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.koreabaseball.com/Record/Player/HitterDetail/Basic.aspx?playerId=60456'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, 'lxml')
html = response.read()
```

then you can use it with `BeautifulSoup`. if it still does not work, there are strong reasons to believe that there is malformed HTML in that page (missing closing tags, etc.) since the parsers that `BeautifulSoup` uses (specially `html.parser`) are not very tolerant with that.

---

UPDATE: try using `lxml` parser:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
tds = soup.find_all('td')
print len(tds)
$ 142
```

Comment: I've always had soup, even without the .read() but I'm always getting [] for item. I applied your edit but no change

Comment: i updated my comment, my opinion is that there's probably some malformed HTML in that page; you should check the response.

Comment: i got some positive results with `lxml`, the caveat is that it's not builtin.